# Teradata: create rows and content for historical data

Tags: teradata

I am really new to Teradata. I am wondering if Teradata could allow me to do the following functionality. I have a product A which has an actual volume history starting from 10/6/2016 to 7/24/2017 (today).

```
Date               Volume
10/06/2016         10
.                  .
.                  .
.                  .
07/24/2017         50
```

When I pull the actual for this product (code: select A.volume from database where date between 20161006 and 20170724), how could I write the code if I want to add 2016010-20161005 rows and make their volume as "0"?

```
Date               Volume
01/01/2016         0
01/02/2016         0
.                  .
.                  .
.                  .
10/05/2016         0
10/06/2016         10
.                  .
.                  .
.                  .
07/24/2017         50
```

I have multiple products (1000+) that need that function. However, I am not able to list the names out together. Is it possible for me to do for all products?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Are you trying to show a volume of 0 where you don't have a row for a specific date?

Comment: Is there one row per product/date, possibly consecutive rows with the same volume? Or date ranges with the same volume? Btw, if you didn't sell the product before 20161006 returning zero is not correct imho.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks Andrew! i am trying to show a volume of 0 starting from 01/01/2016 till the 1st actual available date.

Comment: @dnoeth yes, it is one row per product per date. Take product A as an example, i want to create all the rows for product A starting 01/01/2016-10/05/2016 with 0 volume. and after and on 10/06/2016, there will be real actual. i know it is a strange request, but i need that for other reasons :) Thank you for replying!

Comment: Do you actually store one row per product/date even if the volume doesn't change?

Answer (score 0):

This creates the missing rows:

```
-- find the range of missing dates and expand it to one row per product/date
SELECT product, Begin(pd), 0 AS volume
FROM 
 ( 
   SELECT
      product, 
      Min(datecol) AS pd_end,
      -- double cast needed as LEAST is not implemented for DATEs 
      Cast(Least(Cast(pd_end AS INT)
                ,Cast(DATE '2016-10-01' AS INT)) AS DATE) AS pd_begin
   FROM inventory AS i
   GROUP BY 1
   -- only those with missing dates
   HAVING pd_end > pd_begin
 ) AS dt
EXPAND ON PERIOD (pd_begin, pd_end) AS pd
```

Now `UNION ALL` your existing Select.

Comment: Thank you @dnoeth! How would I deal with the date for the following code if the datecol is like 20.140.101.00, which should mean (2014/01/01)?                  
     Min(datecol) AS pd_end,
      -- double cast needed as LEAST is not implemented for DATEs 
      Cast(Least(Cast(pd_end AS INT)
                ,Cast(DATE '2016-10-01' AS INT)) AS DATE) AS pd_begin

Comment: @XinDu: What's the data type of `20.140.101.00`?

Comment: @XinDu: check the exact type using `help column mytable.datecol;`

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth                                                                           
the type is as below:                                                                                          
Type:N                                                                                         
Nullable: N                                                                                         Format: FN9                                                                                       
Max Length:18

Comment: @XinDu: Check if a `CAST(datecol AS INT)` returns 8 digits, `YYYYMMDD`. If it's actually 10 digits, `YYYYMMDD??`, you must divide by 100: `CAST(datecol AS INT) / 100`. Then you can cast it using `Cast(Cast(datecol AS INT) -19000000 AS DATE)` or `Cast(Cast(datecol AS INT)/100 -19000000 AS DATE)`